# limit misconception, is the result 1 or e?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the result of :

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}(
\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{y}}
1+x)^y
\end{equation*}

Comment: e is the answer.

Comment: You may wish to read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043758/whats-wrong-with-this-reasoning-that-infinity-infinity-0-always).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim \limits_{y \to \infty} \left(\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{1}{y}} (1 + x)\right)^y = \lim \limits_{y \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{y}\right)^y = e$$

Comment: And if I replaced 1 over y by 0, Would it be the same ?

Comment: No, then the limit would be $1$.

Comment: But if I evaluated the inner limit taking into account that y approaches infinity and as a result x approaches zero, the result of it would be exactly one because limits doesn't produce infinitesimal values.

Comment: No, you need to calculate the limits in the right order. You can't just plug in the limiting values in any order. For a simpler example, note that $1 = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: And I guess that right order implies the evaluation of the innermost limit first. And I don't understand the link between plugging the limiting value and the result of the summation.

Comment: You try to calculate $\lim \limits_{y \to \infty} a(y)$, where the function $a(y)$ is given by $a(y) = \left(\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{1}{y}}(1 + x)\right)^y$. From the standard rules for limits we can infer $a(y) = \left(1 + \frac{1}{y}\right)^y$, which yields the result in my post. As for my example, one could argue that as $n$ approaches infinity, the value of $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to zero and we get the sum over zero, which is zero. But this is clearly not the case.